# JavaScriptSerializer jQuery ajax: Requested JSON parse failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

By some reason there's a parsing error with the ajax code below if the service returns more than 4000 lines (everything is correct for less than 4000 lines
). if anyone has a solution for this problem?
merci,

```
                      $.ajax({
                        url: "/service.aspx",
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            dateFrom: strDateFrom,
                            dateTo: strDateTo,
                            visible: ($("#showAll").is(":checked") ? 0 : 1)

                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            options.success(data);
                            self.lineColor();
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                            var msg = '';
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                msg = 'Time out error.';
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                            } else {
                                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                            }
                            console.log(msg); //Requested JSON parse failed.
                        }
```

Comment: I've received **much** bigger JSON payloads via `$.ajax` than 4,000 lines (well, I guess it depends how long the lines are -- let's just say, **really** big payloads) and never had a problem like that. Have you looked at the result that actually arrives at the browser? I suspect your server is cutting it off (buffering problem, time limit, something like that).

Comment: the browser does not receive anything

Comment: I'd start by looking at the code in your `service.aspx`.  See if there's a server setting or something in your code that cuts off your response data after a certain byte limit.

Comment: Your comment _"the browser does not receive anything"_ contradicts the problem in your post.  Again, I'd start by looking at your code in `service.aspx`.

Comment: thank you, I fixed the problem, I had to change my service:                 
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

Comment: @Jawadovic3814:You should post that as an answer (and fix the tags on the question, probably fix the code quoted as well as the problem has nothign to do with jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using .NET as server, for example a ASP.NET MVC Web app.
You will need to update on the web.config or in your JsonConfiguration a maximium value allowed by the server to send JSON information to a client.

You can review the solution in this topic:
[Set an unlimited JSON length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

Comment: thank you, I fixed the problem, I had to change my service: 

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

Answer (score 0):

thank you, I fixed the problem, I had to change my service: 
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;